# sysctl setting net.inet.tcp.keepidle removed in 10.15. Is there a replacement setting?

Tags: macos, network, kernel, tcp

My work requires long-running connections to databases that required this sysctl setting in earlier OSX versions.  Since it no longer exists, these connections appear to remain open, but they disconnect.  The database client awaits the results that never come while the database shows the query as completed.  Is there any setting that can replace the functionality that `net.inet.tcp.keepidle` provided?

Answer (score 2):

We just encountered the same issue. For now, I'm recommending that users that haven't upgraded to Catalina to not do so since there’s no documented workaround or solution for this.

Comment: Minor update. I am testing MacOSX 10.15.2, and I see that `net.inet.tcp.keepidle` is back, sort of. While `sysctl net.inet.tcp.keepidle` shows it has a value of `7200000`, no command allows me to change it's value. For example, I do: 
`sudo sysctl net.inet.tcp.keepidle=180000`
but it returns: 
`net.inet.tcp.keepidle: 7200000 -> 7200000`

Answer (score 2):

This might be old, but I came across this question and since there hasn't been an update, I'd figure I'll add one.
For MacOS Ventura the following commands will work

```
 % sysctl net.inet.tcp.keepidle
net.inet.tcp.keepidle: 7200000
 % sudo sysctl net.inet.tcp.keepidle=600000
net.inet.tcp.keepidle: 7200000 -> 600000
 % sysctl net.inet.tcp.keepidle            
net.inet.tcp.keepidle: 600000
 % sysctl net.inet.tcp.keepintvl          
net.inet.tcp.keepintvl: 75000
 % sudo sysctl net.inet.tcp.keepintvl=10000
net.inet.tcp.keepintvl: 75000 -> 10000
```